# Added domain alias, original domain can not be reached now. Is it normal?

Tags: domain-name-system

I do not remember if I ever experienced something like this, and I want to ask you if it is normal.

So there was a domain name of mine lets say car_123.com. Now I added the bicycle_123.com as a domain alias, and set up bicycle_123.com's nameservers to be the same as car_123.com.

Now, why car_123.com is down too?

Edit:
I think it is an Apache server (if that's available on Solaris?) but not sure, I do not own it. I just really wanted to know the single fact that can adding a domain alias cause the original domain to disfunction?

Comment: show the virtualhost config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is which Webserver do you use?
And how is your configuration?

You should write some more information. When you don't get us information we can not help you and we guess. Here is a link. You can see the how to set the Alias. Then restart. Read this and look if you have some mistakes.

At last check your Apache2 errorlog if you have some problems ;) .

[Apache2 Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/de/vhosts/name-based.html)

Comment: @johnnyjohnnyjohnny : can you close the question? Is it all ok?

Comment: Sorry for not responding mate, accepted your answer. Its all okay now, there was a bug with my hosting provider.